# Abstract method called inside abstract class constructor doesn't see derived class properties

Tags: typescript

The following code should print 'Hello World!' on the screen. Insead it prints `Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. Why?

```
abstract class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.getData());
  }

  abstract getData(): string;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(private item: any) {
    super();
  }

  getData(): string {
    return this.item.id;
  }
}

new Child({id: 'Hello World!'});
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-inheritance-problem?file=index.ts) is a working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the call to `getData` within the `Parent` constructor happens **before** the assignment of the parameter `item` to the private field `item`. That's because the automatic initialization happens **after** the `super()` call, not before it. See `***` comments:

```
abstract class Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.getData());  // *** Calls Child's getData
  }

  abstract getData(): string;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(private item: any) {
    super();                       // *** Calls Parent's constructor
    // ** Automatic initialization happens here, *after* the `super()` call
  }

  getData(): string {
    return this.item.id;           // *** So here, `this.item` is `undefined`
  }
}

new Child({id: 'Hello World!'});
```

This is one of the reasons calling methods from constructors is generally not best practice: They can be overridden by child classes, but the child class's initialization may not be complete (as in your case).

Comment: Do you have a solution for this problem? For now I'm wrappring `getData()` call in `setTimeout`, but it doesn't look good.

Comment: @Humberd - The usual solution is to not call `getData` from the constructor (unsatisfying as that sounds :-) ). Instead, leave it for the subclass to do (ideally, not in its constructor either).

Comment: You can rename the constructor as `init()` and then call `super.init()` in the child constructor. I tested it and it works

Comment: @CristianTraìna - Best not to put it in the child constructor, either, unless it's a final class, and even then it's a bit dodgy... It needs to be a post-construction step. I shouldn't have said "...for the subclass to do..." above. Really, it's for the code using the class to do, after construction.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant calling before `super()` then `super.init()`, what can be wrong with this?

Comment: @CristianTraìna but you have to call `super()` as the first constructor expression.

Comment: @CristianTraìna - The same thing that's wrong with calling `getData` from the constructor: What if a further subclass overrides something that `init` calls?

Comment: @Humberd - I believe Cristian means `super(); super.init();` So the `super()` call would be first.